# How to force asdoc run in English

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flexbuilder, asdoc

My operation system is Window XP in Chinese. 
I'm running flex sdk > asdoc in command line. Asdoc picks up the system default language. 
How can I force it to be run in English language environment?

Comment: @Ty: Could you please "accept" my answer by "putting a green tick beside it"? The tick (now it should be white) is on the left hand side of my answer. Please click it to let it become green. Thank you very much! :-) (I notice that you are a new user and you may not know how to do so.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you needed is the [Microsoft AppLocale Utility](http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/tools/apploc.mspx). It allows you to run an application in the locale you specified. You may change your system locale to English too, but then some of your Chinese applications may not run correctly.

[Here](http://sites.google.com/site/chrislee18a2/applocale) is a step-by-step tutorial (with pictures) by [Chris Lee](http://sites.google.com/site/chrislee18a2/). His tutorial describes how to run Japanese applications on Chinese Windows, but it's similar, just replace Japanese by English and it's all done :-).

Asuka Kenji

(from Hong Kong)